# Ember and Rails, Handling backend errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm attempting to add some backend validation to my Ember/Rails app.  So, reading all the posts I can find, I have done the following:

In my Rails model, I've added validates_presence_of and validates_uniqueness_of entries.

In the Rails controller, I've got a method that is called after attempting save:

```
def validate(permission)
  if permission.valid?
    render json: permission
  else
    render json: {errors: permission.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

In the Ember route, I have the following:

```
actions: {
  create: function(permission){
    var route = this;

    permission.save().then(function(){
      route.transitionTo('permissions');
    });
  }
}
```

When any error is returned from the backend, all I get is a message on the console:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Error: The backend rejected the commit because it was
invalid: {name: can't be blank, description: can't be blank}

"InvalidError@http://127.0.0.1/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:3512
ActiveModelAdapter<.ajaxError@http://127.0.0.1/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:235
superWrapper@http://127.0.0.1/assets/ember.js?body=1:1295
RESTAdapter<.ajax/</hash.error@http://127.0.0.1/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:1530
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://127.0.0.1/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3100
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://127.0.0.1/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3212
done@http://127.0.0.1/assets/jquery.js?body=1:9313
.send/callback@http://127.0.0.1/assets/jquery.js?body=1:9721
"
```

I have the following in my template:

```
{{#if isError}}
  <p>There was an error saving the record</p>
{{/if}}
{{#each error in errors.name}}
  <p>{{error.message}}</p>
{{/each}}
{{#each error in errors.description}}
  <p>{{error.message}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

However, nothing is being displayed on the page, only the assertion error in the console log.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, here.

Comment: I attempted to add code to ember-data.js to try and figure out what was going on and it didn't help me at all.  I am still looking for a solution, here.  It seems as though the error that is coming up in the console is not blocking the execution of the rest of the JS, from what I can tell, but I am not 100% sure of that.  I still cannot figure out why isError and error are not being set properly.  

Has anyone else run into an issue like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle the failure state of the `save`-promise to prevent Ember Data from bubbling the failure up to the console.

```
permission.save().then(function(){
  route.transitionTo('permissions');
}, function() {
  // Couldn't save, do nothing about it.
});
```

That should prevent the assertion error from blocking execution and allow Ember Data to work its magic, adding the errors returned by the backend to your model instance.

Comment: That fixed it.  Now I've got a new problem, so I guess it's time to create another post.  Thanks!